# Why is GeoFire Query only populating Array when method is called twice in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I have a GeoFire query that is only populating my array with the appropriate `keys` after the method `getLocalUsers` is called twice.  How can I get this to happen with 1 call only?  Here is my code...

```
@IBAction func getKeys(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        var allKeys = [String]()
        let geofireRef = self.ref.child("UserLocations")
        let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)
        let circleQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(self.location, withRadius: 200.6)
        circleQuery.observeEventType(.KeyEntered, withBlock: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
            var users = [String]()
            allKeys.append(key)
            for keys in allKeys
            {
                let user = keys
                users.append(user)
            }
            self.localUsers = users
            self.getLocalUsers()
        })
        self.getLocalUsers()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly think it was a Firebase issue, but wasn't sure.  I think the main thing was creating an array in the method for `keys`, `allKeys` so I could loop through and correctly speaking to my public array. Here is how I got it to work. @FrankVanPuffelen please comment...

```
@IBAction getKeys()
{
     var allKeys = [String]()
        let geofireRef = self.ref.child("UserLocations")
        geofireRef.keepSynced(true)
        let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)
        let circleQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(self.location, withRadius: 200.6)
        circleQuery.observeEventType(.KeyEntered, withBlock: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
            var users = [String]()
            users.append(key)
            for keys in users
            {
                let user = keys
                allKeys.append(user)
            }
            self.localUsers = allKeys
            self.friendsNearMeACTN()
        }) 
}
```